# Android Studio re-installation from 1.x.x to 2.3.3 version

Tags: android-studio, github

1) I re-installed Android Studio from 1.x.x to 2.3.3 version. The installation guide said the difference is too big and suggested first the previous version be uninstalled. It appears uninstallation still leaves the previous Studio structure and AndroidStudio and SDK directories still are kept in their places. Then installation built a new version at locations AndroidStudio1 and SDK1.
But when I look in Settings for SDK location it points to SDK rather than to SDK1. Could it be a problem?

2) When trying to "Check out project from Version Control > GitHub" I receive the following error "Cannot run program "git.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The sdk directory name is not a problem. You can always change to any sdk version you want
2. U need to install git first. Have you installed git?